# Unable to insert data in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying out CodeIgniter 4 and I have a problem inserting data.

In my model I only defined the table name, no methods, no nothing. I can display all data in my table but when it comes to inserting data something goes wrong.

My controller code looks like:

```
$data = [
            'sum' => '23',
            'type' => 'in',
            'name' => 'asd'
        ];


        $expense = new ExpensesModel();

        try {
            var_dump($expense->insert($data));

        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }
```

When I call this endpoint using Postman I get a `500 internal server error`.
If I `die('asd')` before the `try-catch` I can see the message so this makes me think something happens during the `insert` method call.

How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you defined within the model was the table name, then you never defined `$allowedFields` (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html):

> This array should be updated with the field names that can be set
> during save, insert, or update methods.

You should probably read through that documentation. Moreover, you would troubleshoot these issues by looking at the logs within your project's `writable/logs` directory, although in this case CI would not consider this a failure as it was you not defining what's allowed into the DB.